# JDataConnect license issue with valid free license

Tags: jdbc

JDataConnect has been used by us many years ago to access Microsoft Access Databases from Java. For a migration project we are tentatively thinking about using it again. In the meantime remote access is possible in principle. I had one successful test a year ago.

Today I am retrying on a different machine with the free license from:
http://www.jnetdirect.com/free-software/jdataconnect-single.html

I have downloaded and installed 
  3.679.232 JDCSetup_4_0.exe

After opening the firewall on port 1150 I can in principle connect using JData2_0.sql.$Driver as a driver and a connection string like:

```
jdbc:JDataConnect:1150//leto/c:\\y_wf\\data\\smartCRM\\smartCRM.mdb
```

then i get the error message:

```
Attempt 1, Connect to JDataServer on server leto port:1150  Result was: java.sql.SQLException: ServerException:You should upgrade the license for this version. The current License is valid only for version 3 
SQLState: 01000
VendorError: 0
```

I am confused since I used the license key from the JnetDirects webpage. There seems to be no version 3 download available. What might be going on here that makes the situation fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JNetDirect support answered the following:

*After further verification, I noticed (and corrected) that while the key provided on the download page before the file is downloaded and the main JDataConnect page was the correct one (the one in red below), the one provided on another page (which Wolfgang used) had 1 different digit. It has been corrected.*